# upgrading my Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade

I am currently running an outdated version of Ubuntu, the 10.04 LTS-lucid linux. how do I download & install an updated version of ubuntu? My browser is firefox and also outdated. when I try to upgrade or download newer version, I keep getting errors that drivers are missing and therefore continue on this old version. Can anyone help or guide me through the process of getting updated?

Comment: I would advise backing up all your data, then downloading and installing 16.04 from scratch, as if you were installing Ubuntu for the first time. In other words, download the .iso file, create a bootable USB stick or DVD drive, and then install Ubuntu 16.04, replacing all the old data on your computer.

Comment: I agree with Nick: Back up your data and install a fresh copy of Ubuntu. If you need help with this, then let us know; we're here to help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) is better because 10.04 is too old for [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) though I wouldn't recommend it in your case because your would have to upgrade 3 times to reach the most recent LTS release, which is likely to cause more issues and work than a backup and re-installation.